# Testing for the optimal number of neurons - Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Im trying to find the most optimal number of neurons for a simple three layer neural network. To do so, i kept the random state of my train/test split fixed and iterated over the number of neurons in the middle layer.

I have 6 parameters that are used to predict a 7th using three layers - Input(6 neurons), hidden(i neurons) and Output(1 neuron).

However, each time I run it I get completely different answers that are not consistent - leaving me with no answer to how many middle layers are "best".

I am using a relatively small dataset - 100 samples. Is the network initalised with random weights/biases? Or is there somethings else im missing? Any help for a tensorflow/keras learner would be a great help!

```
results = []
for i in range(1,10):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2, random_state = 45)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(6,input_dim = x.shape[1], activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(i,activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss = "mean_squared_error", optimizer = "adam")
    monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor = "val_loss", min_delta = 1e-3, patience= 9000, verbose = 0, mode="auto")

    model.fit(x,y,validation_data = (x_test,y_test), callbacks = [monitor], verbose= 0, epochs = 1000)

    pred = model.predict(x_test)
    score = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(pred,y_test))
    print ("Score (RMSE): {}".format(score))
    results.append(score)
```

If it helps, these are the ranges of results im getting for each run (which i thought would be somewhat similar):

```
hidden_layers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Run1 = [1.8300211429595947, 0.7832328081130981,1.144912600517273,1.17598557472229,1.9758267402648926,0.49578756,
        0.6556473970413208,0.696390688419342,0.5946451425552368]
Run2 = [1.422674,1.566674,1.91101,0.86435,1.229273,0.94930,0.7424377,1.2183,0.85622]
Run3 = [1.4056072,1.790036,0.55659616,1.5427451,1.8569565,0.54280525,0.69169235,0.72319275,0.48972014]
Run4 = [0.78299254,1.6193594,0.90550566,1.1891861,0.87066174,0.9133969,1.6031398,0.59118015,0.42699912]
Run5 = [1.842247,1.5956467,1.0008113,0.95922214,2.015607,1.5420123,0.5894643,0.65639037,1.9998837]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event can happen in any Neural Network project. When you run your model with the same input and the same number of neurons, you will different performance.

The main reason for this event is random number generator in Python.

If you want to give the same result for every simulation run, You must set the seed of random number generator.

for example :

```
random.seed(5)
```

In one of my project, I use the following command :

```
random.seed(np.abs(noise_ratio*100))
```

It can contain a variable of your code.

So, If I want to correct your code :

```
results = []
for i in range(1,10):
    random.seed(10)
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2, random_state = 45)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(6,input_dim = x.shape[1], activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(i,activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss = "mean_squared_error", optimizer = "adam")
    monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor = "val_loss", min_delta = 1e-3, patience= 9000, verbose = 0, mode="auto")

    model.fit(x,y,validation_data = (x_test,y_test), callbacks = [monitor], verbose= 0, epochs = 1000)

    pred = model.predict(x_test)
    score = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(pred,y_test))
    print ("Score (RMSE): {}".format(score))
    results.append(score)
```

In addition to this solution, Some researchers believe that you must use k-fold or run your code ten time and give the mean of the result as the final result. I suggest the second way.

write a loop for 10 times and give the mean of results as the final result.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back, i was doing a lot of testing!  Setting the random seed worked when used with me defining the kernel_initializer as "uniform". Thanks!